# PHP mysql varchar to two date filter is not working

Tags: javascript, php, datefilter

Hi  i am importing datas to below table and getting datas based on agent and filter that data based on Date. Date filter only not working in my my file.
plz check where i missed

Hi i have table as per below

```
   create table logistic (cu_name varchar(255) not null, inv_dt varchar(30), 
inv_no varchar(25) not null primary key, qty int, amount int);
```

Php coding

```
<?php  


include('connect.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 


$username=$_SESSION['username'];
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "csvdata");  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM logistic where agent='$username'  ";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title> DatePicker</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
      </head>  
      <body>  
        <style>
        #customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
                <h2 align="center">DatePicker</h2>  
                <h3 align="center">Order Data</h3><br />  
                <div class="col-md-3">  
                     <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-3">  
                     <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-5">  
                     <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info" />  
                </div>  
                <div style="clear:both"></div>                 
                <br />  
                <div id="order_table">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                            <table id="customers">
                      <th width="40%">Dealer</th>  
                     <th width="10%">INVOICE DATE</th>  
                     <th width="20%">INVOICE No</th>  
                     <th width="10%">QTY</th>  
                     <th width="30%">Amount</th> 
<th width="10%">LR No</th> 
<th width="20%">LR DT</th> 
<th width="30%">Transporter</th> 
<th width="10%">Executive</th> 

                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                     {  
                     ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["cu_name"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["inv_dt"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["inv_no"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["qty"]; ?></td>  
                               <td>Rs.<?php echo $row["amount"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["lr_no"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["lr_dt"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["transporter"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["agent"]; ?></td>  
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     }  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
           $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
                dateFormat: 'mm-dd-y'   
           });  
           $(function(){  
                $("#from_date").datepicker();  
                $("#to_date").datepicker();  
           });  
           $('#filter').click(function(){  
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
                {  
                     $.ajax({  
                          url:"filter4.php",  
                          method:"POST",  
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                          success:function(data)  
                          {  
                               $('#order_table').html(data);  
                          }  
                     });  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     alert("Please Select Date");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 </script>
```

This code for Date filter there is no out for this code......

```
<?php  
 //filter.php  
 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "csvdata");  
      $output = '';  


$query = SELECT * FROM logistic              WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(inv_dt,'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST["from_date"]."','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST["from_date"]."','%m/%d/%Y');


      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $output .= '  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="5%">DEALER</th>  
                     <th width="30%">INVOICE DT</th>  
                     <th width="43%">INVOICE NOth>  
                     <th width="10%">QTY</th>  
                     <th width="12%">AMOUNT</th>  
                </tr>  
      ';  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td>'. $row["cu_name"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["inv_dt"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["inv_no"] .'</td>  
                          <td>$ '. $row["qty"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["amount"] .'</td>  
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '</table>';  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

where i am wrong i was used the `$query` in mysql directly its working but in PHP i am not getting result. where i am wrong..

Comment: 1. This can't be your code because it's full of simple syntax errors. 2. Store your dates as *dates*, not strings. 3. Use prepared statements to get rid of all the SQL injection opportunities.

Comment: i cant be store Date as date, because im importing date as string so i need to get as varchar.. just now i am learner, this code collect from weblesson. im modifying for my purpose

Comment: So instead of converting it *once* when you import the data, storing it efficiently, and being able to use indexes; you're going to convert it hundreds/thousands/millions of times per day to do comparisons that are orders of magnitude slower than if you were able to use indexes?